# How do I use ASCIIFoldingFilter in my Lucene app?

Tags: java, lucene

I have a standard Lucene app which searches from an index.  My index contains a lot of french terms and I'd like to use the ASCIIFoldingFilter.

I've done a lot of searching and I have no idea how to use it.  The constructor takes a TokenStream object, do I call the method on the analyzer that retrieves a TokenStream when you send it a field?  Then what do I do?  Can someone point me to an example where a TokenFilter is being used?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The token filters - like the ASCIIFoldingFilter - are at their base a TokenStream, so they are something that the Analyzer returns mainly by use of the following method:

```
public abstract TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader);
```

As you have noticed, the filters take a TokenStream as an input. They act like wrappers or, more correctly said, like [decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to their input. That means they enhance the behavior of the contained TokenStream, performing both their operation and the operation of the contained input.

You can find an explanation [here](http://mext.at/?p=26). It is not directly refering to an ASCIIFoldingFilter but the same principle applies. Basically, you create a custom Analyzer with something like this in it (stripped down example):

```
public class CustomAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
  // other content omitted
  // ...
  public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    TokenStream result = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
    result = new StandardFilter(result);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    // etc etc ...
    result = new StopFilter(result, yourSetOfStopWords);
    result = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(result);
    return result;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Both the TokenFilter and the Tokenizer are subclasses of [TokenStream](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/index.html).

Remember also that you must make use of the same custom analyzer both in indexing and searching or you might get incorrect results in your queries.

Comment: StandartTokenizer is deprecated now IIRC, what's the approach now?

Answer (score 5):

The structure of the `Analyzer` abstract class seems to have been changed over the years. The method `tokenStream` is set to `final` in the current release (v4.9.0). The following class should do the work:

```
// Accent insensitive analyzer
public class AccentInsensitiveAnalyzer extends StopwordAnalyzerBase {
    public AccentInsensitiveAnalyzer(Version matchVersion){
        super(matchVersion, StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        final Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(matchVersion, reader);

        TokenStream tokenStream = source;
        tokenStream = new StandardFilter(matchVersion, tokenStream);
        tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenStream);
        tokenStream = new StopFilter(matchVersion, tokenStream, getStopwordSet());
        tokenStream = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(tokenStream);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, tokenStream);
    }
}
```