# Lucene filter to replace native language letters to normal letter

Tags: regex, lucene, hibernate-search

How to replace native language letters to normal letters via lucene analyzer ? 
In polish we have a 'ą','ę','ć' and I need to replace these to 'a','e','c'.

I tried with

```
 new TrimFilter(new PatternReplaceFilter(source,
            Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]"), , true), true);
```

But this filter is working in wrong way, replace all the chars which not belong to pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ASCIIFoldingFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/ASCIIFoldingFilter.html) which is designed for exactly this purpose. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354948/how-do-i-use-asciifoldingfilter-in-my-lucene-app) and example how to use it.